# How do you create a Google Cloud Function that returns a list of objects from Cloud Storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

So I am trying to return an array of objects. I want to list all of the objects in a particular bucket within google cloud storage using cloud functions. Below is what I have so far. it returns and unhandled promise.

```
export const getAlbums = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    //const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('kais-e4ba9.appspot.com')

    const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket("bucketName");

    resolve(bucket)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
});
```

I wrote a similar function which returns an array of documents from firebase firestore.

```
export const getGenres = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  //if (!context.auth) return {status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in'}
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const array = [{}];
    const ref = admin.firestore().collection("genres");
    // filter out inaActive genres
    const query = ref.where("isActive", "==", true);
    query.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      // Add genres into an array
      const genres = querySnapshot.docs.map(documentSnapshot => {
        return {
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id // required for FlatList
        };
      });
      array.push(genres);
      resolve(array);
    });
  });
});
```

This is what it returns when you log it to the console. I want to display the same result when I call the cloud function to list the objects in a bucket.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kais-e4ba9.appspot.com/o/Screen%20Shot%202020-01-07%20at%207.22.27%20PM.png?alt=media&token=b777d63d-3053-4453-86e7-1e2f19f97a51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the [Cloud Storage list API to](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) list files in a bucket. It's 100% unrelated to Firestore.

Here's the code lifted from the linked documentation:

```
const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

console.log('Files:');
files.forEach(file => {
  console.log(file.name);
});
```

It's trivial to add that to your function. The way you started off with "new Promise" isn't really the best way to go.  We'll go with async/await syntax to make the sample easier to copy in:

```
export const getAlbums = functions.https.onCall(async () => {
    const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

    const storage = new Storage();
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

    console.log('Files:', files);
    return files.map(file => file.name)
});
```

If you just want the default bucket for your project, you can leave off the `bucketName` argument altogether.

Comment: So that actually returns all the files within the bucket beyond the folder level. Is there a way to just return a the folders that are within a directory instead of all the files?

Comment: Yes, the list API has a way to filter by prefix. Read the API documentation to learn how to use it. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles

Answer (score 1):

Using GCP's Cloud Functions and Node.JS you can use the [getFiles()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) method to retrieve the files from a Cloud Storage bucket into a list and then iterate over them as demonstrated there:

```
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
   */
  // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';

  // Lists files in the bucket
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

  console.log('Files:');
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
```